# Use return value of list of values in a SQL Query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to select an id of a table in a select list and fill another field with its description, another field in the same table, but it does not work

I've tried using a dynamic action to set the value to the desc field using the next sql statement: "`SELECT DESC FROM PROVIDER WHERE PROVIDER_ID = :P13_PROVIDER_ID`", but no it returns no value.
When i use "`SELECT DESC FROM PROVIDER WHERE PROVIDER_ID = 1`", it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you described it, in **Set Value** dynamic action you should have put `P13_PROVIDER_ID` into **Items to submit** property.